# jQuery + Select2. Can't get each selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Here's my HTML. I have lots of such elements, as they are added dynamically on page.

```
    <div class="select2-container select_filter" id="s2id_p_data_1_student">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">  
    <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-3">John Doe</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
    <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-3" id="s2id_autogen3" tabindex="-1">
</div>

<select id="p_data_1_student" name="p_data[p_table_data][1][student]" tabindex="-1" class="select_filter" title="" style="display: none;">
    <option></option>
    <option value="2460" disabled="">John Doe</option>
    <option value="2418" disabled="">Paul Kotula</option>
    <option value="2414" disabled="">Andrew Skochelias</option>
</select>
```

I after each selection of select option I need to get all the selected values to disable them in other selects. So one option could be chosen only once.

And here is my jQuery function to handle this. But for some reason it returns only last selected option value

```
function filterSelect() {
        jQuery('select.select_filter').each(function() {
            var selected = jQuery(this).select2('val');
                console.log(selected);
                jQuery('.select_filter option').each(function() {
                    jQuery('.select_filter option[value="' + selected + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: you have two selects with same values and after select one you want to disable values in others?

Comment: Yes. But there can be much more selects, as they are adding dynamically on a page if needed. But their options are the same.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `select2:select` event to disable the other select options, and `select2:selecting` to enable incase of a option change.

try this:-

```js
$('select').select2()

$('select').on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
disableEnableOption.call(this, this.value, false);
});

$('select').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  disableEnableOption.call(this, e.params.data.id, true);
});

function disableEnableOption(value, disable){
  $('select').not(this).find('option').filter(function() {
    return this.value == value;
  }).prop('disabled', disable)
  .parent().select2('destroy').select2();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select id="p_data_1_student" name="p_data[p_table_data][1][student]" tabindex="-1" class="select_filter" title="" style="display: none;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="2460">John Doe</option>
  <option value="2418">Paul Kotula</option>
  <option value="2414">Andrew Skochelias</option>
</select>

<select id="p_data_2_student" name="p_data[p_table_data][2][student]" tabindex="-1" class="select_filter" title="" style="display: none;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="2460">John Doe</option>
  <option value="2418">Paul Kotula</option>
  <option value="2414">Andrew Skochelias</option>
</select>

<select id="p_data_3_student" name="p_data[p_table_data][3][student]" tabindex="-1" class="select_filter" title="" style="display: none;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="2460">John Doe</option>
  <option value="2418">Paul Kotula</option>
  <option value="2414">Andrew Skochelias</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But here are a few problems in my case.
At first I'm using an older version of select2 it's 3.5.4 and here are the events I can use http://select2.github.io/select2/#documentation  
And another problem is, that it should enable/disable selects that are already selected before the page loads. So it should iterate through existing ones, and also analyze the ones that are added with jQuery